# Ruby on Rails sidekiq with airbrake setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, airbrake

What are correct steps to setup sidekiq to work with airbrake on ruby on rails application.

already did:

1. add gem 'airbrake' to gemfile
2. add gem 'airbrake' to gemfile
3. bundle install
4. rails generate airbrake --my_api_key
5. Create file sidekiq.rb with content:

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
       config.error_handlers << Proc.new { |ex,ctx_hash| Airbrake.notify_or_ignore(ex, ctx_hash) }
    end

What are the next steps to make it work?

Comment: What's your Airbrake version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

require 'airbrake/sidekiq/error_handler'